# Control with label doesn't work properly inside Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

Consider the following example:

```
Manipulate[{1}[[i]], {i, {1 -> "a"}}]
```

Execute it and you'll get:

[image]

The correct result will be displayed if you select `a` from the popup menu, but the red box won't go away:

[image]

The issue doesn't raise if I build something similar in a lower level way:

```
DynamicModule[{x}, {PopupMenu[Dynamic@x, {1 -> "a"}], Dynamic@{1}[[x]]}]
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Or it's a bug?

---

OK, it's not a bug. Here's the response from WRI:

> Yes, the first implementation *(this refers to my first code sample)* is an inappropriate way of specifying a control in Manipulate.

Proper ways are shown in [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba)'s comment and [Chris Degnen](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/363/chris-degnen)'s answer below.

Comment: Use `Initialization`, I wouldn't say controllers are responsible for initial values and logical content of body of Manipulate. It's user task to make it reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the initial value stops the error.

```
Manipulate[{1, 2}[[i]], {{i, 2}, {1 -> "a", 2 -> "b"}}]
```